# Swift - Store recently used sublayers in an array (or in variables), and cycle through them with a button?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

My app is dynamically creating sublayers ("myLayer1" below). I am using the following code to set it, which works well

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(myLayer1, at: UInt32(sublayersCount))
```

Obviously each time it runs, there is a new myLayer1, and the old myLayer1 is lost

I want to store these OLD myLayer1's, and cycle through them with an IBACTION ("back" button)

I tried something like the following, to give me 5 possibilities

```
myLayer5 = myLayer4

myLayer4 = myLayer3

myLayer3 = myLayer2

myLayer2 = myLayer1
```

As a test, I dynamically created a few layers, and then ran this via my IBACTION:

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(myLayer2, at: UInt32(sublayersCount))
```

However, it did not display the past layer

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1- If you do

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(myLayer2, at: UInt32(sublayersCount))
```

Then it's equivalent to

```
view.layer.addSublayer(myLayer2)
```

2-

The added layer hides the previous because you may need to  [set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410933-opacity)

```
myLayer2.opacity = // 0.0 --- 1.0
```

3-

Instead of creating vars  [use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410802-sublayers)

```
view.layer.sublayers
```

to access all current sublayers